# How to add a where/detached query property to a Grails domain via AST?

Tags: grails, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

has anyone experience with AST transforms in particular adding a where 'block' to a domain.
In my particular use-case,  I have an AST transform that adds a field to a domain, this works fine, and I also need to add a static where block in there that queries against the new field.
What I'm finding confusing, is determining whether I should be adding a where closure,  or adding a DetachedCriteria, which after all is what the where results in.
In either case, it's also not clear what I should be adding to the class node.
An example of the desired results would be something like

static specialRows = where { notNull 'specialDate' }

I've tried adding this using addProperty, as well as addField, the class type I specify as grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.class with PUBLIC and STATIC modifiers and create a BlockStatement from the string "where { notNull 'specialDate' }".

Unfortunately whatever I'm trying at this point results in NoClassDefFoundError's when instantiating the class I've transformed,  at least it's compiling but fails to execute my test.

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: If you can write by hand a static method that does what you want (probably creating an instance of `DetachedCriteria` and interacting with it), I would be happy to show you how to write an AST transformation to create that method at compile time.  I would leave the `where` closure out of it altogether.

Comment: That'd be great thanks Jeff,    I was looking over some of your other code but still didn't manage to figure out this particular puzzle.

Comment: Just thining about this, this might be tricky, as what I'm doing is essentially replacing an old namedQuery.    With the 'where' form I can write    static someFilter = where { notNull 'name' }   -  but with a DetachedCriteria I'm not sure how it would be instantiated the same..

Comment: Actually this appears to work,  

static DetachedCriteria someFilter = new DetachedCriteria(Customer.class).isNull('dateDeleted')

If you could show me how to add that line via AST, that would be wonderful :)  The 'Customer' class would need to be the class the AST is being applied to though of course.

Comment: is there a reason you prefer to have a static field named `someFilter` as opposed to a static method which returns the query result?  Both are doable.

Comment: (part 1) See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidbrownasttransformation. At https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidbrownasttransformation/blob/94c93493abff4f237f9ee40866d9d5a2346186cf/app/src/main/groovy/davidbrownasttransformation/app/CustomerService.groovy#L12 is code invoking `Customer.listNotDeleted()`.

Comment: (part 2) That method is added by the transformation at https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidbrownasttransformation/blob/94c93493abff4f237f9ee40866d9d5a2346186cf/utilities/src/main/groovy/davidbrownasttransformation/utilities/CustomTransformation.groovy.  `./gradlew run` will invoke https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidbrownasttransformation/blob/94c93493abff4f237f9ee40866d9d5a2346186cf/app/src/main/groovy/davidbrownasttransformation/app/App.groovy.

Comment: The compile time generated `listNotDeleted` method basically does this: `new DetachedCriteria(Customer.class).isNull("dateDeleted").list()`.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't have to use a custom annotation.  In the context of a Grails app you could do the same thing we do in core and apply the transformation to all domain classes, if desired.  The transformation could look for something like, is there a dateCreated property, or does the class implement some marker interface, or some other mechanism that you could use to decide whether or not to have the transformation add the method.  That could simply be boolean logic in the transformation itself.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's really helped.  I made a few tweaks to return a detached criteria via 'getNotDeleted' as there is existing code in the app that appends additional 'findBy's' against notDeleted,  so this appears to work perfectly now.     I noticed when googling there was once some website that generated AST code based on code you could type into a textarea in the browser,  do you use something like this?   This site doesn't appear to be live any longer which is a shame, it sounded very useful.

Comment: "I noticed when googling there was once some website that generated AST code based on code you could type into a textarea in the browser, do you use something like this?" - I don't know about that website but you might be interested in `AstBuilder` which lets you provide the source code that expresses what the transformation is supposed to be generate.  Browse through the tests at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/tree/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/test/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/builder.

Comment: That sounds just as useful, thanks !